# Copying PDF text on iOS in wrong order

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, adobe, pdfkit

I have a PDF that I’m trying to copy and paste the text from. The issue is when highlighting text to copy I can see the highlighting (copying) jumps and doesn’t copy (highlight) in the order in which it is displayed. I’d like to copy as read left to right top to bottom.  On Adobe acrobat or Microsoft Word it is highlighted correctly as displayed. As I need to be able to perform the copy on iOS I’m wondering what the issue could be. When I “copy” the text with PDFKit it is copied in the order it is highlighted as shown in the first animation. I need it to be as show in the second animation which is Microsoft Word.

[image: Using PDFKit]
[image: Microsoft Word]

Comment: If you don't post your code and/or the PDF that is happening the issue how would you expect someone to help you?

Comment: If the PDF had a single text block I am sure this wouldn't happen. Regarding Adobe acrobat behaviour I would need the original PDF to see why it works there and not on iOS.

Comment: The code is irrelevant as it’s my finger swiping the text to highlight it. I’ll try and add a gif to demonstrate if my explanation was not clear with a page example

Comment: I don't think you can do what you are asking with Acrobat. I have tried here and it behaves the same way as PDFKit. It is clear that each column is a text box. Why would you expect to select a line that doesn't exist?. What you have is 5 text boxes (columns) aligned. It doesn't make any sense to select the first line of each text box before selecting the other lines of the first text box (column)

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you. I don’t know about the structure of PDFs so will look into “Text boxes”. I have added the way the same document is highlighted/ copied when opened in Microsoft Word (also Acrobat). As you can see it works as required in the second animation but not on the first. Wonder why one reads the in the intended logical order and the PDFKit way the other. My application is for iOS but the same behaviour occurs when using Apples preview to view the PDF. So suggest that to PDFKit is the problem.

Comment: The issue is definitely the text columns. Don’t know if there is a way to change the way the selection works with PDFKit for multiple columns layout.